# Rewrite URL with 1 or more parameters?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm strugglening with my .htaccess file in orther to achieve this:

```
a.com/male-items  (OR)     
a.com/male-items/popularity   ->    a.com/index.php?g=m&sort-popularity 

a.com/female-items  (OR)     
a.com/female-items/popularity ->    a.com/index.php?g=f&sort=popularity 

a.com/male-items/alphabet     ->    a.com/index.php?g=m&sort=alphabet
a.com/male-items/alphabet/a   ->    a.com/index.php?g=m&sort=alphabet&l=a    
(and same for female)
```

I know it should be something like

```
RewriteRule ^a$ a.com/index.php?q=$1
```

But actually looking into the different mod-rewrite / regex explanations and cheat-sheets doesn't help a lot with getting it to work. The hard part is to understand how do you define the different parametes in the address and then use them in the rewritten url.

(any explanations with your solution would be appretiated)

Comment: Since `q,q2,q3` etc aren't even there in original URI they cannot be used in rewritten query string.

Comment: @anubhava: Of course they can. He probably wants the first segment in q, the second in q2, ...

Comment: @Roy: It's very common for cases like that to rewrite all requests to files that don't actually exist to your PHP file and then parse the REQUEST_URI over there.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I am talking purely in `mod_rewrite` context. Would be happy to see an answer based on `pure mod_rewrite` rules that can generate `q,q2,q3` etc.

Comment: I've edited it so hope now it's less general and more clear

Comment: @Roy: What is `alphabet` is it static string `alphabet`?

Comment: ok posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Use these rules in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^male-items/?$                   /index.php?g=m&sort=popularity [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^male-items/([^/]+)/?$           /index.php?g=m&sort=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^male-items/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$   /index.php?g=m&sort=$2&l=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^female-items/?$                 /index.php?g=f&sort=popularity [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^female-items/([^/]+)/?$         /index.php?g=f&sort=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^female-items/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?g=f&sort=$2&l=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

These htaccess lines redirect all nonexisting files/folders to index.php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

inside index.php you can use: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to parse your parameters.